# Webpack-dev-server doesn't pick up generated HTML file from html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I wanted to create a simple development environment for my react application. I use `webpack-dev-server` and `html-webpack-plugin`. I understand that `webpack-dev-server` doesn't write files and only serves it from memory. When the output files are in the same directory, it works flawlessly, but here's the problem, I wanted the assets to be in `/dist` folder rather than `/` root folder where the generated `index.html` resides.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
- public
  - dist
    * app.js
  * index.html
- webpack
  * dev.config.js
```

Here's my config for the same directory mode:

```
// webpack/dev.config.js

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: assetsPath
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  }
};
```

And here's my attempt for the different directory mode:

```
// webpack/dev.config.js

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/dist');
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: publicPath,
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '../index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

My attempted config is valid, it opens a new browser tab, but not with the content I expected. It only shows a directory listing of `./public` folder with `./public/dist` which is empty and expected, since the development server doesn't write any files.

Anybody know how I can solve this?